# Which database engine is suitable for the 10^10 records?

Tags: mysql, large-data

I am planning to use mysql  to store my datasets.
I have about 10^8 (hundred million) records: 
`ID(int)`, `x(float)`, `y(float)`, `z(float)`, `property(float)`.

Which database engine is suited for this kind of data-sets InnoDB or MyISAM? Or maybe ndb (I have no idea on scalability or performance)?

I am planning to query the static dataset with following questions:

> Select **getRectagularRegion** or **getPointsInSphere**;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am assuming you are trying to store points in 3d space and then find all points within a region.*

How the underlining database codes with a lot of records is a lot less important to you then having a very good 3d spatial indexing system build in to the database.  Without the spatial indexing you can’t do the queries with wish.

You should also *consider* writing your own data storage as a simple 3rd quod tree may give you good indexing depending on how your points are clustered – but using a "off the self" database would be less work for you.

**So I think you need to investigate support for spatial indexing in databases, rather than ask about support for lots of rows.**  Storing lots of rows is a given for most databases these days…

Comment: Thanks  for answer, Yes the data can be indexed by PeanoHilbert curve or similar, I have also the "clusters(x,y,z,radius,Partileslist)"  stored in the separate database I would like to make an efficient jons to extract the individual cluster particles.

Answer (score 0):

Your table seems to be pretty simple and you won't need transactions and foreign keys. So I guess MyISAM would be better suited than InnoDB. But I guess MEMORY might be your fastest choice.

Comment: That'd be a 3+gigabyte memory table, sucking up everything the box has, unless it's a 64bit system